# Can same arraylist have different values in classes?

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an arraylist in the Constants file. Is there a chance that same arraylist has different values in different classes at the same time?
May be the accessing of arraylist happens in different threads also. If it happens so what can I do to fix this? The arraylist does gets modified based on a call back method from Firebase.

NB :- I don't have any code to post here.

Comment: are you modifying content of arraylist?

Comment: Well yes. at some point of time, I do modify the arraylist.

Comment: Then it depeneds on how the arraylist is declared and how your classes get access to it.

Comment: If threads are involved and we don't have the code the answer is: Yes, arraylist could have different values.

Comment: @Kristopher Replacing ArrayList with Vector can this solve the problem?

Comment: debug and check, yes it will have diff values in diff classes. there is no fix. you have to use other list or add values accordingly

Comment: @AmitVaghela Debugging does show different values at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

That's not limited to `List`'s. In every concurrent environment you have to take precautions that there is no race condition or unforeseen mutation. To solve this there are several implementations in the `java.util.concurrent` package. [Here is an overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

There is also the option to use the java tools for concurrency e.g. synchronization, atomic fields, lock objects etc. etc.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html